# svn subtree, update from one repo, commit to other

Tags: svn, svn-externals, subtree, svn-export

A have a big project in a SVN repository. I would like to use some modules of the project in other applications, so I thought about checkout them from my main SVN repository so I can keep my code updated.

How can I "export" one folder / module of my repository so I can checkout only that module to other project? My other projects where I want to include that module are also in their own SVN repository.

In resume, I would like to be able to do SVN update to the main repo but do the commits to the project repo.

I hope its clear what I want to do.

In response to DavidW anwser:

- I have one repository with multiple projects, but i might change this
  if necessary.
- I want to shere the source code. its a php project. I 
  am forking the module. (I have a global generic project and if my
  client needs some specific functions,
- I want to create a separate project for that client (separate in svn also). But i would like to
  have a way to merge some changes made in the main project to the
  client project. (ex: global bug fixes or funcionality).

Comment: You've already specified `svn:externals` in tags as far as I see. So what's the issue? See relevant docs: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html and http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-common-projects.html#tsvn-howto-common-externals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few questions:

- Are you talking about multiple repositories, or multiple projects in the *same* repository?
- If you *borrow* this other module's code, are you keeping it in sync with that other module, or are you forking that module?
- What do you **really** want to share? Do you have to share the source, or the compiled output (`*.so` or `*.a` in Unix C/C+, `*.jar` in Java, etc.).

The answer you'll give depends heavily upon your answers to these questions.

Let's assume that the code is actually shared. What you do in one is what you want done in the other. You make a change in **your** project, the code in the other project also changes.

In that case, use `svn:externals`. This is a property that you place upon a directory. What it does is relate a Subversion URL to a sub-dirctory name. For example:

```
$ svn propset svn:externals "http://svn.vegibanc.com/svn/trunk/project/stuff utils" .
```

WIll place the property on the current directory. When you do an update or checkout, a directory called `utils` will be created in your project, and Subversion will automatically checkout `http://svn.vegibanc.com/svn/trunk/project/stuff` into that directory. It's magic, but like all magic it has both a light and a dark side.

First of all the light side:

This is sharing code between two projects. You make a change in your `utils` directory and commit the change, and the `stuff` sub-directory in `project` will be updated. I use it to build tools into my projects. If I upgrade the tool, all projects get the upgraded tools.

Now, the dark side:

If you define the `svn:externals` just like I showed you, you will deeply regret it. Imagine if you decide to branch your work for a release. Well, your `utils` directory is still pointing to the `trunk` of `project/stuff`. If you branch for release 2.1, and trunk is now working on 2.2, you're going to get stuff in `utils` that you don't want.

Even worse, if you create a tag, that tag will continue to change because that `utils` directory in trunk is still being changed.

Therefore, it is highly recommended that you specify an **exact** version of a URL:

```
$ svn propset svn:externals "-r23283 ^/trunk/project/stuff@23283 utils" .
$ svn propset svn:externals "^/tags/2.3.3/project/stuff utils" .
```

In the first, I am referring to a ***specific*** revision of the URL. It is completely unchanging. If I need to point it to another revision, I need to change the `svn:externals` property itself.

The second is pointing to a specific tag. It's not as *safe* since tags could be changed, but I can treat my external dependency as a release this way. I am using release 2.3.3 of the *stuff* utilities.

Both are using the `^` shortcut which simply means *the Subversion Repository Root*. This way, if you move your Subversion repository to another system, or change from `http` to `svn`, your externals will still work.
Of course, if you do it this way, you'll never be able to change the code under `svn:externals`. And, this isn't what you want.

You can use **relative** URLs too, but they care a bit more dangerous.

Imagine your two projects like this, and you want to make the *stuff* directory an `svn:external` link to the *utils* directory:

```
http://svn.vegibanc.com/svn/trunk/project/foo/stuff
http://svn.vegibanc.com/svn/trunk/project/bar/utils
```

The project is branched together and tagged together. You could do this:

```
$ co http://svn.vegibanc.com/svn/trunk/project/bar bar-trunk
$ cd project-bar
$ svn propset svn:externals "../foo/stuff utils" .
```

This will link the *stuff* directory externally to your *utils* directory. However, it's done in a relative manner. If you do this:

```
$ cp http://svn.vegibanc.com/svn/trunk http://svn.vegibank.com/svn/branches/2.3
```

Your *utils* directory will still be externally linked to the *stuff* directory under the foo project, but they will both be on the 2.3 branch.

Changing code in `bar/utils` will change the code in `foo/stuff` and visa versa. You're still sharing code, but in a way that both projects are still in the same branch.

Later on, if you tag like this:

```
$ cp http://svn.vegibank.com/svn/branches/2.3 http://svn.vegibank.com/svn/tags/2.3.0
```

Your tag 2.3.0 is unlikely to change because the external links and what they link to are all encased by that tag.

The above is assuming you're sharing the code, and changes in either project should affect the other.

A better way to do this is for `foo` to create a compiled object of some sort (like a JAR file or a *.so) that could be stored on a release server. You treat this compiled object as its own project with its own versioning, and your project will depend upon a particular release of this object. Unfortunately, that doesn't always work.

If you are simply forking the code, do a `svn cp` from one spot in the repository to the other. You can make your changes without affecting the other project and visa versa. Even better, you could merge changes back and forth between the two locations to keep them somewhat in sync.

Hope this answers your question. If you can expand your question and give us more details on what you want, I'll be able to update my answer.

Comment: Hi David.I have answered to your questions in my post. Based on your answer I think what I need is the cp command. I can create a branch/tag for each client project and, for example if I make some bug fix in the master branch I can merge that bug fix with all my clients projects branch. Have I understand it correclty? Many thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: @Bruno-P Yes. If your project is part of the same repository as the other project, and you don't want the changes to be completely in sync, the best way to handling this is to use `svn cp` to create your project. Code changes from one won't *automatically* show up in the other. However, you can use `svn merge` to sync the changes.

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to use shared code inside Subversion repository - it's svn:externals
- If you want port changes from mainline on shared code into customer-specific version of shared code - it's "Vendor branches" in svn lingo

Combined a) and b) will give you needed result

1. Select some node (outside trunk of customer's repository), which you'll link to shared node in dev-repo
2. Create external definition (with PEG-revision preferred, if you'll have to have easy time-back for the cost of manual updates of definition after commits to dev-repo)
3. Copy node to the location, where in must be in live project (`svn cp ...`)
4. Code...
5. When you have changes in dev-repo, which you want to transfer into customer repo - update externals to needed revision, merge "Vendor" node to "Live"

Sample:

If you'll have in customer's repo

- /vendor/lib (where lib is directory from foreign repo)
  */trunk/common/lib (customer's version of the lib above)

incorporating changes from lib-mainline is merge from /vendor/lib to /trunk/common/lib (in the corresponding node of Working Copy for your trunk)

David's notes about externals are still valid, correct and useful